# Arduino driving servo through SSR 'flickers' on and off

Tags: arduino

thank you for your help in advance.
I have a circuit configured as shown in [image: this image]. I got this arrangement from an earlier thread.
An arduino controls a DC solid state relay, and it works fine when my load is a simple LED. The arduino is controlling through a digital output header and using the digitalWrite() function, so I don't think PWM has anything to do with it. The arduino is powered by an external source: not USB.

Making that load a motor as shown in the image causes problems though. I have an LED in series so that I can see when the relay is closed and power is being delivered. It flickers at about 4-5 Hz I would say.

My relay is the [CN024](http://www.crydom.com/en/Products/Catalog/c_n.pdf).

The relay is capable of delivering up to 3.5 A at 24 VDC. It is powered by a 7 VDC switched adaptor source right now. The power source can deliver up to 2 A. It is zero crossing.

The motor it is powering is a [simple servo motor](https://www.parallax.com/product/900-00008). It is rated for up to 6V and typically draws 140 mA.

Despite this, is the flickering caused by a high current inrush and the circuit is being broken by a protective circuit in the servo? Though my knowledge is limited, it seems like all the requirements have been met: the SSR circuit is being closed, and there can be enough voltage supplied and current delivered. I tried putting a diode in series in order to drop the voltage from 7  V to (7-0.6)=6.4 V just to make sure the voltage wasn't too much.
Any ideas?
Code included below, if it's important:

```
    //Servo Potentiometer Control

#include <Servo.h>

const int SERVO=10; //Servo on Pin 3

const int POT=A0;  //POT on Analog Pin 0

const int RELAY=3;

Servo myServo;

int val = 0;

void setup(){

 myServo.attach(SERVO);

 pinMode(POT,INPUT);

 pinMode(RELAY,OUTPUT);

 digitalWrite(RELAY,HIGH);

 Serial.begin(9600);

}

void loop()

{

  val=analogRead(POT);  //Read Pot

  val=map(val,0,1023,0,179);//Scale it to the servo range

  myServo.write(val);  //Sets the servo

  Serial.println(val);

  delay(15);

}
```

Comment: What image?????

Comment: Have you tried putting a series resistor of about 1kohm in the LED wire i.e. the wire that feeds the opto from your MCU? It is important because the diode in the opto will take about 40mA as you have drawn it.

Comment: Yes, there is a 470 ohm resistor in series there to limit the current to 10 mA. The SSR needs about 10 mA at its control input to operate I think.

Answer (score 1):

> Power Precautions
>   -Do not use this servo with an unregulated wall-mount supply. Such powe supplies may deliver variable voltage far above the stated
>   voltage.

The above is from the datasheet I found [here](https://www.parallax.com/sites/default/files/downloads/900-00008-Continuous-Rotation-Servo-Documentation-v2.2.pdf)

I think you may be providing too much voltage to the servo.

What is your actual wiring diagram for the setup? Have you joined the Ground signals from the wall adapter to your arduino? Have you tried writing to the servo in microseconds instead? Like in the loop function:

```
val = analogRead(POT);
unsigned int microsecs = 1000+val;
myServo.writeMicroseconds(microsecs);
```

Comment: also your loop runs faster than a single servo control loop. Try delaying for 40-50 milliseconds before doing another control loop. A servo needs to receive a "command" every 20ms normally. Not entirely sure how the servo library deals with what you have there

Comment: Hi, I really appreciate your help.

I followed your suggestions by: tying all grounds together: arduino, and motor power source.

Trying your code and adding adequate delay.

Unfortunately I am still having problems.

Comment: @LickMyEyeball what problems are occuring now?

Comment: They are identical to earlier. This is my first time operating a relay. I can try a 5 V linear regular in series with the load?

Comment: @LickMyEyeball is your analog read even working? Do you have a multimeter? Can you check voltages over the relay and servo and other various things?

Comment: @LickMyEyeball I see the updated schematic now - can you please remove BOTH the LED (L1) and the other series diode (D2).

Comment: LED and redundant diode removed. Voltage drop across power-side of SSR: 2.37 V   When putting the voltmeter across the Servo, voltage fluctuates wildly, then settles to ~7 V, the value of the switching power source.I suppose this means that the circuit is being blocked to DC for some reason?

Comment: @LickMyEyeball your LED is probably using 3V and the diode is probably using another 0.5->1.1V. Not only that, but because the motor isn't conducting/moving properly, it's not acting as a proper resistance/pathway to ground either, that's why it's making the LED flicker.

Comment: @LickMyEyeball oh I see... that's pretty random. you can put the LED back into the circuit if you want, just make it parallel to the motor to ground, with a resistor in series (to limit it's current).

Comment: @LickMyEyeball what's the current output rating of your 7V wall supply? Have you got a 1000uF or similarly large beefy capacitor hanging around you could put in parallel between the relay output and ground?

Comment: I'd move this to chat if I had the reputation: thanks for all your help. The wall supply is rated for 2 A, which should be enough for the current inrush I read about. The max I expected was about 1.8 A for an instant. As for the capacitors, I will put a few in parallel to approach 1000 uF and do as you suggest!

Comment: @LickMyEyeball I can't find an option to move to chat either, strange.. Anyway you do not need 1000uF, but a few hundred will help.

Comment: I added a capacitor bank as per the updated image. Unfortunately the SSR has a 5.5V voltage drop across it now, which isn't enough to drive the load (LED is pretty much off)

Comment: @LickMyEyeball your schematic says digital pin 2, but your code says pin 3, which is it?

Comment: It's running out of header number 2. The difference is from my experimenting. I will match to the code you have and send the relay signal out of header number 3.
Your suggestion to add the capacitors improved the circuit: it moves but is still underpowered.

While this is a different problem altogether, it is resonating. I operated this servo off of a 9V battery (through a linear regulator) and it went alright and I didn't see this behavior.

Comment: @LickMyEyeball interesting. It's possibly just a shit wall power supply

Comment: Oh that's unfortunate. They rate for voltage and current: I wish they would rate for shit supply. I bought this adaptor for my learning electronics. Any pointers for sourcing a good supply? Actually I have a better question: can I drive this little motor from my Arduino 5V header?

Comment: @LickMyEyeball no, do not power the motor from the 5V header. It's the tiny little linear regulator on the Arduino, which should never pull more than 100mA.

Comment: Great, thanks again for everything and have a good day!

Comment: @LickMyEyeball if you can, report back on any improvements from using a better power supply